# How to select specific rows based on specific condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am working in Pandas Python. I am trying to select specific rows based on specific condition. From the below dataset, I want the system groups which has Type 1 in it. System groups which don't have type 1 can be ignored.

| System | Type |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 2 |
| D | 3 |

Required Output

| System | Type |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |

System A and B is obtained in the required output becuase it contain the Type 1 value. C and D groups has been ignore due to no Type 1 in them. I am trying to do with groupby but unable to extend this function to check for presence type 1 in it in the condition. Please help

Code to generate dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
  
data = [['A', 1], ['A', 2], ['A', 2],['A',3],['B',1],['B',2],['C',2],['C',3],['D',3]]
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['System', 'Type'])
```

Answer (score 1):

let's say the table variable is df . Then the code will be

```
sys = list(df[df['Type'] == 1]['System'].values)
ans = df[df['System'].isin(sys)]
```

ans is your preferred table. I am sure there are better ways but hopefully this works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```py
df[df['System'].isin(df[df['Type'] == 1]['System'])]
```

```
  System  Type
0      A     1
1      A     2
2      A     2
3      A     3
4      B     1
5      B     2
```

First, you filter the df to only rows with Type=1, and select the `System` column. Then you filter the df to only includes rows where `System` is in that list

It might be faster to get the values into a set and search in it

```py
df[df['System'].isin(set(df[df['Type'] == 1]['System'].values))]
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can use `where clause` it will be much faster than conditional selection

```
selectedvariables=df.where(df['Type']==1)["System"].dropna()
print(df[df["System"].isin(selectedvariables)])
```